# Vue-cli VS module bundler and task runner

Tags: vue.js, webpack, gulp, vue-cli

Here’s my situation: I’m a junior developer who has to create the front end of a big web app, but although I have *worked* on these kinds of apps before I never had to set the whole environment *around* the app, everything was already in place every time and I could just to use the tools.

I’m asked to choose, among others, which module bundler and task runner to use. Though the more info I find about this the more I get the feeling that every time it’s something that vue-cli is already handling.
Why should I install gulp or webpack when `vue build` compiles the typescript, minify the js and css, and bundle all of that in unique files (and others) ?

Is it precisely the whole point of vue-cli, or am I missing something important here ?

Thank you in advance for your advices :)

Comment: Vue CLI uses `webpack` underneath. No need to install `webpack`. You can use gulp if you want to but there is no need when it comes to minifying css/js and compiling your `vue` templates into js code

Comment: thx for your answer that's indeed what I was thinking, there doesn't seem to be real need for these if I'm only using the most basic functionalities

Comment: vue-cli is what you need. It runs everything under the hood (webpack etc) and if you need to do something it doesn't do you can create your own webpack, babel etc files and it will recognize them.

Comment: @Jabberwocky cool I didn't know that, it's indeed pretty useful thx for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by Varcorb and here : https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-cli-vs-module-bundler-and-task-runner/65891 it *is* indeed the whole point of vue CLI so no need of gulp or webpack for basic projects